# BLE writeCharacteristic and readCharacteristic issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am a beginner of BLE in my case BLE write characteristic true but BLE `readCharacteristic` failed.I followed this [working example](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/) but I changed the service `UUID` and getCharacteristic `UUID`.But till i receive the read failed.Kindly help anyone i tried many ways thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to work with, or the device you are trying to connect with is hard to tell what's going on. My bet is that the device you are trying to use doesn't have the custom characteristic you are trying to write. I recommend that you download the BLE scanner app for android and use it to identify the services availdable in your BLE device.